# VS2013 compilation error: non-static data member initialization by pointer to member

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

This code doesn't work in VS2013, but works in GCC (http://ideone.com/WgmlT2). Who is right and is there some workaround?

```
struct A
{
    void(A::*fn)() = &A::do_work; // C2276: '&' : illegal operation on bound member function expression
    void do_work() { cout << "Hello, world!"; }
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    (a.*(a.fn))();
}
```

I need it in something like macro router so initialization in constructor initialization list isn't suitable.

```
#define ROUTE(url, ...) \
    route_inserter_base route_inserter_##url = make_route_inserter(*this, #url, &this_t::url##_action); \
    mystream url##_action

ROUTES_BEGIN(app)
ROUTE(getdata)(int idx) {
    return data[idx];
}
ROUTES_END
```

Comment: That works with both g++ and clang++. I suspect that it is not supported yet in vs2013 (or a bug).

Answer (score -1):

Not very sure I completely understand your question, but for member function pointer, you can try:

```
struct A;
typedef void (A::*pClassFun)();
struct A
{
    void do_work() { cout << "Hello, world!"; }
    void call_do_work(pClassFun fun)
    {
        (this->*fun)();
    }
};


int main()
{
    A a;
    a.call_do_work(&A::do_work);
}
```